Functions such that the *integral* of the Fourier transform is non-negative?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be in $L^1$, with its Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ also in $L^1$. What is a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ so that
$$\int_{-\infty}^x \widehat{f}(t) dt \geq 0$$
holds for every $x$?
Assume, if it helps, that $f$ is even, continuous and of compact support, with $f(0)=1$.

If the question were to ensure that $\widehat{f}(t)\geq 0$, we would all know the answer -- it is necessary and sufficient for  to be of the form ∗. Now, if I haven't miscalculated, $\int_{-\infty}^x \widehat{f}(t) dt$ is the Fourier transform of the distribution $-\frac{f(x)}{2\pi i x} + \frac{f(0)}{2} \delta(x)$, but I have no idea of what it would mean for that to be a self-convolution!

That's related to your computation but did you try to introduce, for all $x$, the tempered distribution $g_x$ (sorry I am too lazy to compute it now) such that $\widehat{g_x} = \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,x)}$ and then write your condition as " the integral of $\widehat{f}\widehat{g_x} = \widehat{f\star g_x}$ has to be non-negative for all $x$ " which in turn should be equivalent to $f\star g_x(0) \geq 0$, by Fourier inversion theorem (compact support of $f$ could be useful here to define the convolution product $f\star g_x$). I don't know if such a condition would be useful though ...

@AymanMoussa This gives me the condition $\frac{1}{2} + \widehat{\frac{i f}{2\pi x}}(t)\geq 0$ for every $t$. That's the same as what we had before, no?

If your function is continuous and of compact support then you can use Whittaker–Shannon interpolation formula (or something like that) and you will see that the Fourier transform is written in terms of sinc function.

@AndronickArutyunov Aha? Details? Yes, assume it's continuous and of compact support.

@HAHelfgott I mean the following. Here there is theorem 4.11 for band limited functions, i.e. the Fourier image is finitely supported. I mean that there is an analogue theorem for functions with inverse Fourier transform is finitely supported. But at the moment I can't find it, sorry.
Note that functions of your interest can be also described by Paley-Wiener Theorem (mentioned paper, Th 4.4), but it gives an inequality to the "wrong side".

@HAHelfgott yes I think it's right, so the suggestion was useless sorry :/
